# Force cleartype fonts in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, cleartype

Firefox allows you to force webpages to use the fonts you specify by unchecking 
"Allow pages to choose their own fonts instead of my selection above" in the advanced fonts settings. I use this to force cleartype fonts in Firefox.

Is there a way to do this in Google Chrome?

Comment: I found an extension that allows the replacement of a handful of sans-serif fonts https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/acgbckcjlpneapibaifnhpjnnakijihm . It's primarily for font snobs, but allows you to choose a custom font (e.g. Calibri) to use instead of Arial. Unfortunately it doesn't allow you to replace Times New Roman or Courier New.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an *enhancement-request* bug report open at [Chromium's Google Code bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2387) to enable ClearType support. It's a priority 2 so it will hopefully be fixed a few releases from now (but maybe that's just wishful thinking).

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping there was a hidden config for this already. I'll leave the question open a little while longer in case someone has any other suggestions.

Comment: "a few releases from now" is unfortunately (as you rightly surmise) absolute nonsense. That bug report's been sitting there from 2008 :(

Comment: Actually, Chrome now respects the system setting. See [bug 96393](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=96393).

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP clear type is enough for Chrome.
Just turn on Display->Appearance->Effects->"Use the following method to smooth edges of screen fonts"->"Clear Type" and you are done.

Comment: I do have cleartype enabled. I was asking about forcing webpages to use fonts with cleartype hinting if possible (e.g. Cabrili, Cambria, Consolas). 

The cleartype fonts as they're usually referred to are much easier to read, in my opinion, than the default fonts that websites usually specify (i.e. Arial or Times New Roman).

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into this when I was also searching for how to force chrome to use my fonts. Found [Ubuntu 10.10 (unified font style) v1.0](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmpnnplimbnbmdaigmnajmbdcinhpddj/related?hl=en) It forces chrome to use Ubuntu fonts. But can not select other than Ubuntu fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which font you want Chrome to display, follow the steps below.

1. Go to the directory: C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets
2. Open "Custom.css" using Notepad (The file will be blank if you didn't add anything inside).
3. Type this line of code in:

   > -* {font-family: "font name";}
4. Don't type the hyphen (-) in, this is added so as to make the asterisk (*) display, instead of bullet point.
5. Replace the "font name" with your own font, this is just an example.
6. Save the file, and launch Chrome.

This will make Chrome's default font become the font you want it to display, also applies to webpages, but some website developers would probably do something that it won't force ALL content to be displayed in your desired font. To fix this, follow the steps below.

1. Once you added the code and saved the CSS files from the above steps, open the CSS file again.
2. This time, add in any rubbish characters, for example, a hash (#) can do the trick. Example code:

   > -* {font-family: "Segoe UI#";}
3. Now launch Chrome. Go to Settings by typing "chrome://settings" without quotes to access Settings menu (or press the icon with 3 lines and click Settings)
4. In the "Search settings" field, type "fonts" without quotes and click Customize fonts...
5. Under "Standard Font", choose the fonts in the list and Chrome will display it.

Again, don't type the hyphen in Step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is the [Font Rendering Enhancer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-rendering-enhancer/hmbmmdjlcdediglgfcdkhinjdelkiock) extension:

> Font Rendering Enhancer comes from Opera Font Rendering by thunder13.
>   Darker and clearer text on almost every page (http and https).
>   Modified and ported Mac OSX Font Rendering by proxxy (from Opera on
>   Presto engine).
>
> The windows browsers render the fonts based on the normal sub-pixel
>   rendering without implementing Font smoothing, anti-aliasing as
>   noticeable as Mac OSX. This tweak applies text to be displayed more
>   anti-aliased using CSS3 property. So modern browsers supporting CSS3
>   and userstyle support would be able to support it.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Comment: Link is to the Font Rendering Enhancer extension in the chrome store

Comment: I know :). I've updated your answer for you. Now it it is less likely to be deleted as a link-only answer.