# Enable Safari-like font rendering on Chrome (on Windows)

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force cleartype fonts in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/239161/force-cleartype-fonts-in-google-chrome)

Do you know if there is any option on the Google browser to enable that nice font-rendering like on Safari?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified, so I'll presume you're using Windows.

Try the [gdipp project](http://code.google.com/p/gdipp/).

Disclaimer: I have not tested it, just found it after a bit of searching.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension "[Anti-aliased text for all](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ndnanojhgckocbkbnfpfcanpinoedimh)". I personally use it and fonts seems to be sharper.

Not too sure if that is what you want - Safari's font rendering is quite bad on the Windows version.

[image: Anti-aliased text for all]